# Segmentation fault on finding the kth smallest element in C

Tags: c

The problem involves finding the kth smallest element in an unordered integer array of size `n` where (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000000). The approach is to identify the maximum value in the input array, create a new array of length `max value + 1`, initialize it to zero, use each element in the input array as an index in the new array, and finally declare and initialize a `count` variable. Loop through the new array, accumulating counts, and find the kth smallest element.

It resulted in a *segmentation fault*. I spent a considerable amount of time debugging but couldn't locate the issue.

I tested it on PTA, and it worked for n = 50, but failed for n = 80. Interestingly, testing it with n = 10000 on PTA showed no issues as well, but testing it on my Code::Blocks later had problems again.

Problem Statement:
7-1 Kth Smallest Element

Given an unordered integer array of size n `(1 ≤ n ≤ 1000000)`, which may contain identical elements, find the kth (1 ≤ k ≤ n) smallest element. Note that the kth smallest element refers to the element at the kth position after sorting the array in ascending order.

Input Format:
Each input file is a test case. The first line of each file provides two positive integers, n and k. The second line contains n integers separated by spaces.

Output Format:
Output the value of the kth smallest element.

Sample Input:

```
10 4
2 3 5 12 4 9 3 8 2 9
```

Sample Output:

```
3
```

Code Constraints:

Code length limit: 16 KB
Time limit: 400 ms
Memory limit: 64 MB
Stack limit: 8192 KB

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    int num[n];
    scanf("%d", &num[0]);
    int max = num[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        if (num[i] > max)
        {
            max = num[i];
        }
    }
    int sort[max + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
    {
        sort[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sort[num[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
    {
        if (sort[i] != 0)
        {
            count += sort[i];
            if (count >= k)
            {
                printf("%d", i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw6Wz.png)
[Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTF0a.png)

I wrote a Python script to generate test cases that meet the requirements. Python script:

```
def generate_input(n, k):
    # Generate n random integers as array elements
    arr = [random.randint(1, 1000000) for _ in range(n)]

    # Write the array elements to a file
    with open("input.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(f"{n} {k}\n")
        file.write(" ".join(map(str, arr)))

# Generate a test case that meets the conditions of the problem, for example, n=10000, k=5000
generate_input(10000, 5000)
```

Comment: Can you use [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)?

Comment: You're supposed to demonstrate the problem, but you don't claim to have any problem for the input you provided. So that's useless. Please provide an input for which your program actually fails. I'm guessing it's an array with a "very large" `max` value, which causes `int sort[max + 1];` to overflow the stack.

Comment: Does your problem statement say that the integers in your array are non-negative, or no greater than the size of the array?

Comment: With your generator you must be extremely unlucky, but I second the comment above, since you do not have constraints on the actual n values, you can have a very large int and not enough space on the stack for sort[]

Comment: I think I found the bug in your program. But how would I verify that? I'd like to have a test on which your program crashes and my improved version runs well. But only you have this test. Oh well, I won't post my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to operate with different arrays.  This approach will be far simpler:  You don't need to store the whole array, this consumes a lot of memory and is not scalable.

If you have to check the k-th smaller integer, then create a `k` elements array `list`, and store the smallest k elements of the array int that list, your output will be the last of those, as the array starts empty, hold a variable that stores how many elements you have.  You start filling the array (don't worry about the order), if the input ends before the array is filled, you have just to say that there's no such kth-element (if your input has less than k elements, its impossible to get the k-least element, we use the value `0` as it is not a valid input to indicate no such element was found ---remember that the input was restricted to 1...1000000 interval)  So it's expected that, when you have more than k, you start to have more elements to start shifting out.  I do the insertion by exchanging the element with  the one at insertion point  position, and go up to the end of the array, ending with the last element shifted out.

We will have a function that provides us the elements (just to be input agnostic):

#### kth.c

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define END_OF_INPUT      (0)

#define RED "\033[1;31m"
#define GRN "\033[1;32m"
#define ECL "\033[m"

#define FLG_SHOW_COL      (1 << 0)
#define FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS   (1 << 1)
#define FLG_SHOW_IN       (1 << 2)

int flags = 0;

int
stdin_provider(void)
{
    int out;
    if (scanf("%u", &out) != 1) {
        return END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    return out;
} /* provider from stdin */

/* comparison function for qsort below */
int
compare_int(
        const void *_a,
        const void *_b)
{
    const int *a = _a, *b = _b;
    return *a - *b;
} /* compare_int */

const char *set_col(const char *col)
{
    return flags & FLG_SHOW_COL
        ? col
        : "";
}

void
print_array(
        int k,
        int *list,
        int lft,
        const char *fmt,
        ...)
{
    if (flags & FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS) {

        char *sep = "";
        va_list args;

        va_start(args, fmt);
        vprintf(fmt, args);
        const char *color = set_col(GRN);
        printf(": list = {");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (i == lft) {
                color = set_col(RED);
            }
            printf("%s%s%u%s",
                    sep,
                    color,
                    *list++,
                    set_col(ECL));
            sep = ", ";
        }
        printf("}");
        fmt = va_arg(args, char *);
        if (fmt)
            vprintf(fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
    } /* if */
} /* print_array */

int
find_kth(
        int      k,
        int    (*prov)(void))
{
    int list[k], in;
    size_t sz = 0;

    /* fill the array */
    while (sz < k && (in = prov()) != END_OF_INPUT) {
        list[sz++] = in;
    }

    /* we have no more data return error */
    if (sz < k) {
        /* we got not enough data, so we cannot have a
         * k-smallest element, return 0 to indicate error.
         */
        return 0;
    }
    /* sz == k */
    print_array(k, list, 0, "BEFORE SORTING:", "\n");
    qsort(list, k, sizeof list[0], compare_int);
    print_array(k, list, k, "AFTER  SORTING:", "\n");

    /* if last element was valid, we have a full array,
     * then do the following process to with each excess
     * element. */
    while ((in = prov()) != END_OF_INPUT) {
        int ignorable = (in >= list[k-1]);
        if (flags & FLG_SHOW_IN) {
            printf("IN: %u%s\n",
                    in,
                    ignorable
                        ? " ignored"
                        : " insert");
        }
        if (ignorable) {
            continue;
        }

        /* we need to find the insertion point and shift
         * the elements back, dropping the last one. */
        int left = 0, right = k-1;
        /* in >= list[left] && in < list[right] */
        while (left < right - 1) {
            const int mid = (left + right) >> 1;

            if (in >= list[mid]) {
                left = mid;
            } else { /* in < list[mid] */
                right = mid;
            }
        }

        if (in >= list[left])
            left++;
        print_array(k, list, left,
                "BEFORE INSERTION",
                " in=%u @ pos=%d\n",
                in, left);
        for (; left < k; left++) {
            int temp = list[left];
            list[left] = in;
            in = temp;
        }
        print_array(k, list, left,
                "AFTER  INSERTION",
                " out=%u\n",
                in); /* in now is out */
    } /* for */

    return list[k-1];
} /* find_kth */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    unsigned k = 8;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "acik:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'a': flags |= FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS; break;
        case 'c': flags |= FLG_SHOW_COL;    break;
        case 'i': flags |= FLG_SHOW_IN;     break;
        case 'k': k = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 10);
            if (k < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid k < 1 (%u)\n", k);
            }
            break;
        }
    } /* while */

    printf("find_kth(%u, stdin_provider) -> %u\n",
        k, find_kth(k, stdin_provider));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

it will produce the following trace so you can see how the algorithm works (you can eliminate the traces to get the final result):

```
$ kth -aick 4 <<EOF
> 2 3 5 12 4 9 3 8 2 9
> EOF
BEFORE SORTING:: list = {2, 3, 5, 12}
AFTER  SORTING:: list = {2, 3, 5, 12}
IN: 4 insert
BEFORE INSERTION: list = {2, 3, 5, 12} in=4 @ pos=2
AFTER  INSERTION: list = {2, 3, 4, 5} out=12
IN: 9 ignored
IN: 3 insert
BEFORE INSERTION: list = {2, 3, 4, 5} in=3 @ pos=2
AFTER  INSERTION: list = {2, 3, 3, 4} out=5
IN: 8 ignored
IN: 2 insert
BEFORE INSERTION: list = {2, 3, 3, 4} in=2 @ pos=1
AFTER  INSERTION: list = {2, 2, 3, 3} out=4
IN: 9 ignored
find_kth(4, stdin_provider) -> 3
$ _
```

---

A second round to the algorithm has revealed that it is not necessary to maintain the list of elements in order, and results in a bit more simpler and compact code (no need to `qsort()`, no need to searh for the insertion point and the most, no need to shift the elements back to make the largest to shift out)

If we have the address of the top element in the list, we can still ignore all elements that are larger or equall than the largest, and we can put the element ---for input that is less than the largest--- in that place)  Then we need just to get the maximum element position again.  As this has to be done only when an array modification is done, we can take advantage of the initial filling of the array (to get the initial maximum) and then only search for it after a new input element has been added.  The new source will be simpler (no binary search, just an assignment and a new search for the maximum)

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define END_OF_INPUT      (0)

#define FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS   (1 << 1)
#define FLG_SHOW_INPUT    (1 << 2)

int flags = 0;

int
stdin_provider(void)
{
    int out;
    if (scanf("%u", &out) != 1) {
        return END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    return out;
} /* provider from stdin */

void
print_array(
        int k,
        int *list,
        int bold,
        const char *fmt,
        ...)
{
    if (flags & FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS) {

        char *sep = "";
        va_list args;

        va_start(args, fmt);
        vprintf(fmt, args);
        printf(": list = {");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            printf("%s%s%u%s",
                    sep,
                    i == bold ? "[" : "",
                    *list++,
                    i == bold ? "]" : "");
            sep = ", ";
        }
        printf("}");
        fmt = va_arg(args, char *);
        if (fmt)
            vprintf(fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
    } /* if */
} /* print_array */

int
find_kth(
        int      k,
        int    (*prov)(void))
{
    int list[k], in, max_pos = 0;
    size_t sz = 0;

    /* fill the array */
    while (sz < k && (in = prov()) != END_OF_INPUT) {
        list[sz] = in;
        if (list[sz] > list[max_pos])
            max_pos = sz;
        sz++;
    }

    /* if (sz < k) we have no more data and return error */
    if (sz < k) {
        /* we got not enough data, so we cannot have a
         * k-smallest element, return 0 to indicate error.
         */
        return 0;
    }
    /* sz == k now we have, list[max_pos] is the maximum
     * value of the array */
    print_array(k, list, max_pos,
        "AFTER INITIALIZATION",
        " max=%u @ pos=%u\n",
        list[max_pos], max_pos);

    /* if last element was valid, we have a full array,
     * then do the following process to with each excess
     * element. */
    while ((in = prov()) != END_OF_INPUT) {
        int ignorable = (in >= list[max_pos]);
        if (flags & FLG_SHOW_INPUT) {
            printf("INPUT: %u%s\n",
                    in,
                    ignorable
                        ? " ignored"
                        : " insert");
        }
        if (ignorable) {
            continue;
        }

        /* we can put it on the position of
         * the maximum value */
        list[max_pos] = in;

        print_array(k, list, max_pos,
                "AFTER SUBSTITUTION  ",
                "  in=%u @ pos=%d\n",
                in, max_pos);

        /* now we need to find a new maximum value position */
        max_pos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[max_pos])
                max_pos = i;
        }

        print_array(k, list, max_pos,
                "NEW MAXIMUM         ",
                " max=%u @ pos=%d\n",
                list[max_pos], max_pos);
    } /* for */

    return list[max_pos];
} /* find_kth */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    unsigned k = 8;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "acik:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'a': flags |= FLG_SHOW_ARRAYS; break;
        case 'i': flags |= FLG_SHOW_INPUT;  break;
        case 'k': k = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 10);
            if (k < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid k < 1 (%u)\n", k);
            }
            break;
        }
    } /* while */

    printf("find_kth(%u, stdin_provider) -> %u\n",
        k, find_kth(k, stdin_provider));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

this will show the following traces, when run against the same data:

```
$ kth -aick 4 <<EOF
2 3 5 12 4 9 3 8 2 9
EOF
AFTER INITIALIZATION: list = {2, 3, 5, [12]} max=12 @ pos=3
INPUT: 4 insert
AFTER SUBSTITUTION  : list = {2, 3, 5, [4]}  in=4 @ pos=3
NEW MAXIMUM         : list = {2, 3, [5], 4} max=5 @ pos=2
INPUT: 9 ignored
INPUT: 3 insert
AFTER SUBSTITUTION  : list = {2, 3, [3], 4}  in=3 @ pos=2
NEW MAXIMUM         : list = {2, 3, 3, [4]} max=4 @ pos=3
INPUT: 8 ignored
INPUT: 2 insert
AFTER SUBSTITUTION  : list = {2, 3, 3, [2]}  in=2 @ pos=3
NEW MAXIMUM         : list = {2, [3], 3, 2} max=3 @ pos=1
INPUT: 9 ignored
find_kth(4, stdin_provider) -> 3
$ _
```

IMHO, if you are given this example as some codility test for a job recruiting process, you should (and I would hire you) deliver the first solution, as the second requires a bit of thinking and a bit of running the code first to realize that it can be optimized this way.  If you come to me with this solution, you will probably be rejected, as a plagiarist.

Comment: yes, but I needed it to test, and it's not bad to show how to use the getopt library.  Anyway, it's a complete and verifiable example, with also a lot of extra noise to show how the algorithm works internally.  Something rare to see today.  You can copy/paste the code, edit it an post an answer withoug such noise.  Professional programming does require this extra noise, so why don't show it here?

Comment: A better choice for the `qsort` comparison function is `int
cmp(const void * pa, const void * pb) {
    const int a = *(const int *)pa;
    const int b = *(const int *)pb;
    if (a > b) return +1; if (a < b) return -1; return 0;
}`, the one you have right now is non-transitive.

Comment: That requires a cast, and so, it is error prone.  I have already used it but now I prefer my approach.  The latest version doesn't require sorting, nor insertions, so no comparison function at all, and a bit more efficient.  Do you prefer two tests than a single subtract? :)

Comment: Why should I need a transitive function?. `qsort()` simply doesn't require a transitive function.  And how transitive? but anyway, it is indeed transitive,  if comp(a, b) < 0 and comp(b, c) < 0 then compp(a, c) < 0   You are wrong, I'm afraid.  You can use the same approach to test that if comp(a, b) > 0 and comp(b, c) > 0, then comp(a, c) > 0.  and also for equality.